# Rails - how to validate two fields are unique when combined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

How can I make sure that:

once I have

```
type: 1 style: 2
```

I can't add

```
type: 2 style: 1
```

because the combo should be unique?

I thought:

```
validate :unique_relationship

def unique_relationship
  (user_id.to_s + friend_id.to_s).uniq
end
```

but don't think the uniq would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
def unique_relationship?
  self.class.where("(user_id = ? and friend_id = ?) or (user_id = ? and friend_id = ?)", user_id, friend_id, friend_id, user_id).empty?
end
```

If the result set is `empty?`, no relationship between `:user_id` and `:friend_id` exists.

Answer (score 0):

I would absolutely use a database constraint in this case, because the database can do this much more efficiently than you can in rails.

You'll want to create a multi column index

```
add_index :table, [:column_one, :column_two], unique: true
```

Note, this means that creation/update might throw exceptions now.  If you expect that to be a rare case, that's probably okay.  If not, you'll want to do something about that.